# How to find the correct nested resource when dealing with many to many relationships in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, join, nested-resources

Bear with me as I'm a Rails noob.  I have a basic league system.  League -> Seasons -> Divisions -> Teams.  I would like my Divisions and Teams to belong to any number of seasons.  My models are as follows...

```
class Season < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :league
  has_many :season_division_teams
  has_many :divisions, :through => :season_division_teams
end

class Division < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :league
  has_many :seasons, :through => :season_division_teams
  has_many :season_division_teams
  has_many :teams, :through => :season_division_teams
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :league
  has_many :season_division_teams
  has_many :seasons, :through => :season_division_teams
  has_many :divisions, :through => :season_division_teams
end

class SeasonDivisionTeam < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :season
  belongs_to :division
  belongs_to :team
end
```

What I want to be able to do ultimately is say given that i'm in season '1', what divisions do I have, and then given those divisions what teams are part of those divisions (for the given season).

```
Season.Find(1).divisions.all do |division|
    # Do something with the teams that make of the division (for that season)
    # division.teams.count
end
```

I just can't get my head around how to do this in Rails, which seems very simple to me in SQL.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Edit:

Just to clarify, I'm trying to get the teams for a given season (with their divisions).  With my model I know I can get the divisions for a given season.  I just need to the the teams for those divisions and season.

Thanks again.

Comment: BTW, this is nice example of 5th normal form if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

Use `includes` to [eager-load](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) the associations and avoid the N+1 performance hit when getting the teams:

```
@season = Season.includes(:divisions => :teams).find(1)
divisions = season.divisions
teams = divisions.map(&:teams).flatten.uniq
```

If you want to get all divisions and teams for *that season only*, then do this differently.  Firstly, add the following line to your Season model:

```
has_many :teams, :through => :season_division_teams
```

Now you can simply do:

```
@season = Season.find(1)
divisions = @season.divisions
teams = @season.teams
```

Note that there's not much point in eager loading here since the database will only be hit twice (rather than once and then once again per division).

**UPDATE**

Lastly, if you want to get all divisions for the season, and then all teams within those divisions for that season, do as follows. You could use this code:

```
@season = Season.find(1)                     
divisions = @season.divisions
divisions.each do |division|
  puts "Division: #{division.name}"
  division.teams.where(:season_division_teams => {:season_id => @season.id}).each do |team|
    puts "Team: #{team.name}"
  end
end
```

But using eager-loading is the preferred method like so:

```
@season = Season.find(1)                     
divisions = @season.divisions.includes(:season_division_teams => :teams).
                    where(:divisions => {:season_division_teams => {:season_id => @season.id}})
divisions.each do |division| 
  puts "Division: #{division.name}"
  division.teams.each do |team|
    puts "Team: #{team.name}"
  end
end
```

This should eager load all teams for the associated divisions that meet the conditions that we merged in.

Comment: I tried your solution, but when I try to loop through teams and get the team.name, it simply prints out 'Team' and not 'Patriots' or 'Bruins', etc.  Where am I going wrong.

Comment: @joero4: Can you post the code you are using to print out the names?

Comment: <%  season2 = Season.includes(:divisions => :teams).find(2)
  divisions = season2.divisions
  teams = divisions.map(&:teams)
  teams.each do |team| %>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <%= team.name %>
   </td>
   <td>
   </td>
  </tr>
 <% end %>

Comment: @joero4: hmm, this looks right - have you tried restarting your server process?  Also, have you verified that the attribute you're looking for is called `name` and that it contains the data you think it does?  You can also try doing this in console and examine several of the team objects.

Comment: I restarted my server, and still nothing changes.  I actually changed .name to .id, just in case and I get an error undefined method `id'.

Comment: Ok, I tried going through the console, and in order to get the team name I had to do this..teams[0][1].name.  The mapping is creating a 2 dimensional array (???).  Also, I'm getting two results when I should only be getting 1.  I have two records for one team in my db.  But the team is linked to two different seasons.  I should only get one team.  Any idea why I would get two?

Comment: Aha, I forgot to clarify that `map` will return an array of arrays.  To fix this you can use `flatten`. And if you only want unique teams without duplicates, you can add `uniq` after that - updated answer.  The only thing remaining is that this doesn't filter out teams of associated divisions that are only linked for _other_ seasons.  Will this be a problem for you?  If so, there's one more thing to add here...

Comment: We are almost there.  Thank you so much.  I need to only see teams associated with a given season.  So if we have Season 1 - Div 1 - Team 1 and Season 2 - Div 1 - Team 2, I should only get Team 1 if I want teams for Season 1.   and not see Team 2 even though Team 2 is associated with Div 1.   Make sense?  Thanks Again.

Comment: I'm going to mark you answer as correct, as you have basically answered my question, but how could I figure out which teams below to what divisions?  That will give me divisions and teams, but not broken down for teams per division which is what I really wanted.  Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you so much.  A couple of issues (I'm so sorry if I'm driving you nuts).  The first solution works, but for every team associated with a division the results are printed out.  3 team, 3 sets of results.  The second solution didn't work.  First there is a type with include(s).  After fixing that, I get an error that "divsions"."season_division_teams" column does not exist.  Thanks again.

Comment: Oh dear...same error.  'SQLException: no such column: divisions.season_division_teams'